# Creating a document library with Sharepoint powershell using template

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I am trying to create a document library from a template. The template name has spaces in it through.

```
#Add the SharePoint snapin
write-host "Loading powershell module" -ForegroundColor Cyan
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ea SilentlyContinue

# specify the source and destination sites
$sourceWeb = "http://mysite";
$DestinationWeb = "http://mysite/Search";


# get the source and destination sites web objects
$sourceWebObj = Get-SPWeb $sourceWeb;
$DestinationWebObj = Get-SPWeb $DestinationWeb; 



$listTemplate = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListTemplateType]::"My Enterprise Documents"
$DestinationWebObj.Lists.Add("Documents_Archieve","My Doc Library",$listTemplate);
```

The error:

```
Exception calling "Add" with "3" argument(s): "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: Invalid argument 'template' to SPListCollection.Add() method.  Please pass an argument of the appropriate type."
At C:\script\archive3.ps1:32 char:29
+ $DestinationWebObj.Lists.Add <<<< ("Documents_Archieve","My Doc Library",$listTemplate);
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your variable $listtemplate will be null as you can only get the default templates in this manner. To get your custom template you will need to do something like this:

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://yoursite
$web = Get-SpWeb http://yoursite/yourweb
$custTemplate = $site.GetCustomListTemplates($web)
```

You can confirm your template is available:

```
$custTemplate | select name
```

Then create a list like this:

```
$DestinationWebObj.Lists.Add("Documents_Archieve","My Doc Library",$custTemplate["My Enterprise Documents"]);
```